# Hidden reference to equation

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, mathtools, subequations

How to make a hidden reference to an equation, such that `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}` is overridden (assuming it is active)?

Alternatively, how to switch off `showonlyrefs` temporarily (regardless of whether it be set or not)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command `\noeqref{<label>}`. This ensures that the corresponding equation has a number regardless of the value of `showonlyrefs`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:ab}\noeqref{eq:ab}
  a=b
\end{equation}
%
Some text follows
%
\begin{equation}\label{eq:bc}
  b=c
\end{equation}
%
Some text follows again
%
\begin{equation}\label{eq:dc}
  d=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]